# How to fix Pyinstaller Mac Os error when creating onefile app

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Hello i am trying to use pyinstaller in Mac OS 10.13
But i receive that error:

```
teloss-Mac:client telos$ pyinstaller --onefile gui.py 
94 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
94 INFO: Python: 2.7.15
114 INFO: Platform: Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
116 INFO: wrote /Users/telos/Desktop/Telos-Monitor-Tool/client/gui.spec
134 INFO: UPX is not available.
137 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/Users/telos/Desktop/Telos-Monitor-Tool/client',
 '/Users/telos/Desktop/Telos-Monitor-Tool/client']
137 INFO: checking Analysis
138 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
138 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
141 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
258 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
273 INFO: Caching module hooks...
280 INFO: Analyzing /Users/telos/Desktop/Telos-Monitor-Tool/client/gui.py

Syntax error in /Users/telos/Desktop/Telos-Monitor-Tool/client/gui.py
  File "/Users/telos/Desktop/Telos-Monitor-Tool/client/gui.py", line 98
     msg.exec()
            ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The strangest thing is that on linux and windows that script went fine and no syntax error in that gui.py

If in Mac Os i use `python gui.py` script work fine, but if use python launcher receive same error
part of code that send error:

```
    @staticmethod
    def _donation_messages(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msg.setWindowTitle("")
        msg.setWindowIcon(QIcon('img\icon.ico'))
        msg.setText("")
        msg.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByKeyboard|Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        msg.exec()
```

Thx for help

Comment: change `msg.exec()` to `msg.exec_()`

Comment: thx.  Can you plz explain why i use `os.getcwd` and then use join config to this path and in Linux and Windows after compiling all is ok. In Mac OS the `os.getcwd` don't get corect path? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Add @eyllanesc wrote th help fine, thx Need to change `msg.exec()` to `msg.exec_()`